# Using Google Apps Script to post data

Tags: php, google-apps-script, gmail, add-on

I am trying to post JSON data to the URL from google script but getting the above error.

> "Bad request: http://api.dev/api.php/project_task/ "

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSXPO.jpg

Here is my code:

```
function testApi() { 
var data = {
   "user_id": 12,
   "username": "Son Ha",
   "creator_id": 35,
   "creator_username": "Simon Ha",
   "status": 1
  };
 var options = {
   "method" : "post",
   "contentType" : "application/json",
   "payload" : JSON.stringify(data)
  };
 UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://api.dev/api.php/project_task/', options);
}
```

My PHP Api code : http://api.dev/api.php/project_task/ :

```
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
$request = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'],'/'));
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'base_test');
mysqli_set_charset($link,'utf8');
$table = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_]+/i','',array_shift($request));
$key = array_shift($request)+0;
switch ($method) {
    case 'GET':
        $sql = "select * from `$table`".($key?" WHERE id=$key":''); break;
    case 'PUT':
        $sql = "update `$table` set $set where id=$key"; break;
    case 'POST':
        $sql = "INSERT INTO projecttasks 
(user_id, username, creator_id, creator_username, status)
    VALUES (1, 'Tom B. Erichsen', 1, 'Stavanger', '4006')"; break;
    case 'DELETE':
        $sql = "delete `$table` where id=$key"; break;
}

$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
if (!$result) {
    http_response_code(404);
    die(mysqli_error());
}
if ($method == 'GET') {
    if (!$key) echo '[';
    for ($i=0;$i<mysqli_num_rows($result);$i++) {
        echo ($i>0?',':'').json_encode(mysqli_fetch_object($result));
    }
    if (!$key) echo ']';
} elseif ($method == 'POST') {
    echo mysqli_insert_id($link);
} else {
    echo mysqli_affected_rows($link);
}
mysqli_close($link);
```

Anybody has any idea about where I am going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: what about the `///`, you have one extra `/` in there if the error message is accurately written here.

Comment: The codes are messy; you should separate the GET, POST, DELETE and PUT codes into different blocks. Also, `$key` does not necessarily an integer, which your query might fail, even worse, suffer from SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @thank Raptor and Vytautas

I updated my question. 

This PHP code is sample code for testing. I can post data from real domain but can not post from my localhost ( http://api.dev )

Comment: You don't really need PHP, you can update your MySQL database directly from apps script using the JDBC API.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Apps Script: Possible to send http requests to a local server that's not on interrnet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42114838/google-apps-script-possible-to-send-http-requests-to-a-local-server-thats-not)